# Serial flash memory page rewrite issues

Tags: flash

I am using M25P32 serial flash memory for my project. Befero using this IC, my project used AT45DB321. There are major differences between these memories, because AT45DB321 supports Page erase function and support Page rewriting, which means, corresponding bytes of the Page can be overwritted without using Page erase.
My program uses Page program function to update and store data into memory. But now, using M25P32 I cannot update Page data without erasing entire sector. Let say I have a Page which is 256 bytes size. I would like to update this page. Is there any solution to update Page without erasing entire sector and affecting neighboring pages?

Comment: Why did you select a device that doesn't support the functions that you need? But in any case, if you implement a proper wear-leveling algorithm -- even a relatively simple-minded one -- the lack of page erase shouldn't be a major issue.

Comment: This is not new project and this project used AT45DB321 last 5 years.. but these times (because of semiconductors crises), it is difficult to order AT45DB321 and I have to implement something new to my project. There are no function compatible IC replacement for my old flash memory.